# HTTP 1.1 Python Client Simply Not Working

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, http-get

I have been rearching for HOURS today and all day yesterday. I am completely new to python and am taking a computer networking course. I am simply stuck on this problem so any help would be immensely appreciated.
I am trying to run a simple HTTP request with GET and HEAD calls. So I would type in the command line while running the client python script: python web_client.py host:port/path [METHOD] where method is GET and HEAD. Nevermind the head which I haven't even gotten to yet, I can't get the GET method to even work. I keep getting the same error.

Here is my server.py file:

```
from socket import *
import socket

serverSocket = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) #resets if there is a problem

serverPort=8080

serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print("Server is Ready")
while True: 
    try:
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        print(addr)
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        message.decode()

        print('Msg is: ')

        #Path is second part of HTTP header denoted by [1]
        filename = message.split()[1]
        print('File name is: ', filename)
        f = open(filename[1:])

        #Store the entire contenet of the requested file in a temporary buffer
        outputdata = f.read()

        # Send the HTTP response header line to the connection socket
        connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n")

        # Send the content of the requested file to the connection socket
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n")
        # Close the client connection socket
        connectionSocket.close()

    except IOError:

        connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n")
        
        connectionSocket.close()
      
serverSocket.close()
```

And here is my client file which has been giving me nightmares (I am sorry if this is obvious to many of you more experienced programmers and I already feel ridiculous that I can't figure this out) but any direction would be helpful:

```
import socket
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re
import os
import sys


socket.setdefaulttimeout = 0.50
os.environ['no_proxy'] = '127.0.0.1,localhost'
linkRegex = re.compile('<a\s*href=[\'|"](.*?)[\'"].*?>')
CRLF = "\r\n\r\n"

def GET(url):
    print("Get method")  
    url = urlparse(url)  
    path = url.path
    print("path", path)
    print("url", url)
    if path == "":
        path = "/"
    HOST = url.netloc  # The remote host
    PORT = 8080          # The same port as used by the server
    # create an INET, STREAMing socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("HOST", HOST)
    print("PORT",PORT)
    print("s", s)
   
    s.settimeout(0.30)
 
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
   
    # set up TCP connection - THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS!!!!!!
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

    print("Got here msg", (path, CRLF))#NOT SHOWING UP BECAUSENOT GETTING TO THIS STEP!

    msg = "GET%s HTTP/1.1%s" % (path, CRLF)
    print("msg request:\n", msg)
    
    # send HTTP get request
    s.send(msg.encode())
    
    dataAppend = ''

    # wait for response from server
    data = (s.recv(10000000))
    if not data: print('error, no response')
    else:
        dataAppend = dataAppend, repr(data)

    # shutdown and close tcp connection and socket
    s.shutdown(1)
    s.close()
    print('Received', dataAppend)

def HEAD(url):
        print('Head method')

if sys.argv[2] == "GET":
    GET(sys.argv[1])  

elif sys.argv[2] == "HEAD":
    HEAD(sys.argv[1])
```

The error that I am getting is:
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11011] getaddrinfo failed

It seems that the error is around where I am trying to set up the socket connection. I have read it could be due to a bug in the library or some systems config issues? Can any help please - I don't think its the code (it may be) but more of something behind the scenes around figuring out how to connect?

Comment: *". I have read it could be due to a bug in the library or some systems config issues? "* - unlikely a bug in the library, more a bug in your code or how you use it. The problem is from looking up the HOST name, i.e. resolving the name given to an IP address. Unfortunately this information is not provided in your question, even though according to your code you print out the name. To get better help  provide the full error you get (stacktrace) and also how exactly your code is run (arguments)

Comment: Once you pass this error you might realize that your GET requests is broken in multiple ways too, i.e. it would not work with a real HTTP server but at most with your broken one which does not do real HTTP. Please don't seconds guess how such request work - but follow standards and other documentation instead.

Comment: So your comments provided minimal assistance. Also, regarding "once you pass this error you might realize that your GET requests is broken in multiple ways too, i.e. it would not work with a real HTTP server but at most with your broken one which does not do real HTTP." I know it is broken, hence why I am asking here. I am new to this in numerous ways. If you have more constructive feedback, that would be helpful instead of pointing out the obvious. But thank you for your feedback regardless.

Comment: To solve the problem with getaddrinfo one need to know what HOST is - which is unknown since you neither give output nor arguments nor detailed stacktrace. *"I know it is broken, hence why I am asking here."* - You only asked for advice regarding getaddrinfo. You will run into more problems once the getaddrinfo is solved, but this would be another question. I've only tried to inform you that there will be more problems after the current one, so that you might look at these early.